# arrange R plots: how can I arrange plots of the VIM package?

Tags: r, grob

I would like to generate multiple plots using marginplot() (VIM package) and then arrange them into one big figure. I tried to use grid.arrange (grid/gridExtra package) and it did not work. The error was, that a grob was expected as input. So I tried to first convert the marginplot into a ggplot (as.ggplot) or grob (as.grob) but this did not work. Has anyone an idea how to arrange the plots?

```
library(VIM)
library(ggplotify)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

x <- cars[, c("speed", "dist")]
marginplot(x)
y <- cars[, c("speed", "dist")]
marginplot(y)

p <- qplot(1,1)
#p2 <- as.ggplot(marginplot(x))
r <- rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="grey90"))
grid.arrange( r, p,p, r, ncol=2)
```

I created a small code with cars, where I managed to arrange grey squares and qplots. put I cannot add the marginplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base plots this error occurs. Learned here: [grid.arrange from gridExtras exiting with "only 'grobs' allowed in 'gList'" after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838870/grid-arrange-from-gridextras-exiting-with-only-grobs-allowed-in-glist-afte)

`grid.arrange` is intended to be used with "grid graphical objects" (grobs), such as `ggplot2`.

One could find an equivalent grid-plot or use a base-graphics approach to stacking plots.
Try this:

```
library(VIM)

x <- cars[, c("speed", "dist")]
y <- cars[, c("speed", "dist")]

par(mfrow = c(2,2))
marginplot(x)
marginplot(y)
plot(rnorm(100))
hist(rnorm(100)) 
par(mfrow = c(1, 1)) #reset this parameter
```

[image]